# Overriding the default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, default-scope

Could someone help me to find out how to override `default_scope`.

In my view I have to show all `matches`, not only `{ where("match_date >= now()") }` I need to display all matches. I have some reasone to use default_scope. I am very new in Rails. I tried to use unscoped, but it didn't help or I used it not properly. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar_match
end

class BarMatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
  belongs_to :match
  has_many :reservations
end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, through: :bar_matches
  has_many :bar_matches, dependent: :destroy
  default_scope { where("match_date >= now()") }
end
```

**Controller**

```
 @reservations = Reservation.where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

**View**

```
- @reservations.each do |reservation|
  = reservation.bar_match.match
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this gem in your Gemfle

```
gem 'unscoped_associations'
```

then

https://github.com/markets/unscoped_associations

or you can:

```
class BarMatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  def match
    Match.unscoped { super }
  end
end
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Works greate. Thanks Igor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`unscoped`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/unscoped) method

```
Match.all          #=> SELECT * FROM matches WHERE match_date >= now()
Match.unscoped.all #=> SELECT * FROM matches
```

**EDIT:**

Try adding a new scope and use it

```
class BarMatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  belongs_to  :unscoped_match, -> { unscoped }, foreign_key: :match_id, class_name: "Match"
end
```

Use it in view

```
reservation.bar_match.unscoped_match
```

Comment: But how can I implement in my case. I can't do something like @reservations.each do |reservation|
  = reservation.bar_match.match.unscoped.all

Comment: Can I somehow use unscoped in view?